# Adding Menu in Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a Action Bar where i want to add one help button using Menu. I am using Android 3.0.
My Menu code is like below:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item  
    android:id="@+id/help_btn"
    android:icon="@drawable/help"
    android:title="Help"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
/>
```

Now how can i add this menu in the action bar??

Answer (score 26):

The same way you create regular menus:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#OptionsMenu

Comment: But is onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) method applicable for Android 3.0? Because when i am writing that method in my activity, it is not called.

Comment: Yup, it sure is :) It's working in my Honeycomb projects. That's all you'll need.

Comment: Below is my Activity code:  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        Log.d("Debug", "It is coming here::::::::::::");
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    
    public boolean onCreateOptionMenus(Menu menu)
    {
     Log.d("Debug", "It is coming here");
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.menus, menu);
     return true;
    }

Comment: I don't think you need this: `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);`

Comment: yes. But it is not calling the onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) method.

Comment: What's your API version target?

Comment: That's weird. Are you using the Holo theme?

Answer (score 3):

Update;

You can inflate a menu like this @override

Put in res/menu/YOUR_MENU.xml

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.YOUR_MENU, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a pretty old question, but I'll throw an answer at it anyway.  If you're dealing with a Fragment, you'll need to let the system know you'd like to contribute to the action bar or `onCreateOptionsMenu` will never be called.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10049807/725752

Comment: Yes! Thank you. If trying to modify the actionbar menu items from a fragment you absolutely must call this from onCreateView().

Answer (score 0):

Now with Jetpack Compose , you don't need separate menu XML

```
Scaffold(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                topBar= {
                    TopAppBar(
                        title = {
                            Text(text = "Create New Recipe")
                        },
                        navigationIcon = {
                            IconButton(onClick = { }) {
                                Icon(
                                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,
                                    contentDescription = "Back"
                                )
                            }
                        },
                        backgroundColor = Color.Blue,
                        contentColor = Color.White,
                        elevation = 2.dp,
                        actions = {
                            IconButton(onClick = {
                                uiController.hideSoftKeyboard()

                                ...
                            }) {
                                Icon(
                                    contentDescription = "Help",
                                    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.help)
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }, content = {
                    }
                })
```

Here `topBar` contains code for Action Bar and `actions` contains menu button

Reference- https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2021/08/03/jetpack-compose-1-0-0-sample-codes/