# ActionBar items not showing up using FragmentTabs example

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and have a little problem.  In the Fragment Tabs example, there are four tabs.  Three of them add items to the ActionBar, but the first one doesn't (Labeled "Simple").  I'm trying to get that first one to add an item to the ActionBar, but it doesn't work for some reason.  The only difference I can see between the tabs is that the "Simple" one is a SherlockFragment, and the other three are SherlockListFragments.

The SherlockListFragments use the onCreateOptionsMenu as usual to populate the ActionBar, but when I add that to the SherlockFragment and trace it, it doesn't even get called and no items appear on the bar.

Can I not add ActionBar items with a SherlockFragment?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did you call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`?

Comment: That works if I put it in the onCreateView method. I haven't ever needed to call that before, and I've coded a few activities. Can you explain why that would need to be done now?  It is just Fragments vs Activities or something?

Comment: Fragments require explicitly defining whether or not they will be contributing options items to the menu. See the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html